# Timer в определенный день в Service

Tags: android, таймер

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы таймер запускался в определенное время время и дату, даже не смотря на то, что приложение было закрыто (не Forse Stop) и был перезапуск. Если телефон выключится, а момент наступил пока телефон был выключен, событие все равно должно выполниться. Как это лучше сделать? Я пробовал TimerTask в MainThread, но он выполнился даже сегодня, а не в назначенную дату.

```
public void runTimerService() {
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    Date date = new Date();
    date.setDate(1);
    date.setMonth(7);
    date.setTime(0);

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(Consts.TAG, "TIMER TIME!");
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(timerTask, date);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте AlertManager и BootReceiver для автозапуска установки задачи в AlertManager-е, для хранения задач database.

Создание задачи

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationsReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mRepository.getNotificationsHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mRepository.getNotificationsMinute());
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

Получение

```
public class NotificationsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationsManager.with(context)
            .checkForShowNotification();
}}
```

BootReceiver

Манифесте

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

BootReceiver

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "BootReceiver was starting - Only debug", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    NotificationsManager.with(context)
            .updateNotifications();
}}
```